# Pipe two filenames (with spaces) through xargs in one command

Tags: bash, imagemagick, command-line-interface, ls, xargs

Often I find myself wanting to merge the two latest screenshots I take into one image. I want to use ImageMagick to, in one command line through xargs (?), to merge the two latest files sorted by date.

So far I have the following, but it has trouble dealing with the spaces in the filenames. I can't seem to figure out how to get this done.

```
ls -t | head -n 2 | sed 's/\n/\x0/' | xargs -0 -n 2 -I images convert images -append -quality 75 combined.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Change sed command to `sed 's/.*/"&"/'`.

Or use this pure bash solution:
Replace the sed command in your pipeline with this code:

```
while read x; do echo "'$x'"; done
```

AND Remove the `-0` option from xargs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel installed:

```
ls -t | head -n 2 | parallel -n 2 convert {} -append -quality 75 combined.jpg
```

It is designed to deal properly with space, ', " and other weird characters.

See the intro videos http://pi.dk/1

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
At first I did not see that you needed to sort them in order of the most recent files and I provided an answer using find.

Unfortunately find does not allow to sort files. Some workaround is needed to sort them properly.

Here is proposition to sort your files by time using find:

```
find -type f -printf '%T+_%p\n' | sort -r | head -n 2 |  sed 's/[^_]*_//' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 2 -I images convert images -append -quality 75
```

Note: this command will work even if you have "_" or spaces in your file names.